# Input type=“text” css

Tags: css

такой вопрос. Есть `Input`

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your title here..." />
```

Как поменять цвет шрифта "placeholder"?

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=input%20type%20text%20placeholder%20color&es_th=1

Answer (score 6):

Пример

```css
input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #f00;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #f00;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #f00;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Text placeholder" />
```